# Can't push view controller while in its own function

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I made A UIViewController which has a Completion handler function on it because it has to load data from a database, the code for the segue there is :

```
func S0000 () {

    let V = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("V0003") as! V0003

    V.Cv { (Con) -> Void in

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            self.showViewController(V, sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

This throws the error :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How could I make it work and what am I doing wrong.

And just for information I found out that when I run it this way It works but ofcours is not finished loading when pushing to It becuase It pushes before the completion handler returns.

```
func S0000 () {

    let V = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("V0003") as! V0003

self.showViewController(V, sender: self)

    V.Cv { (Con) -> Void in
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {    
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
V.Cv { (Con) -> Void in

NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
    let V = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("V0003") as! V0003
    self.showViewController(V, sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you cant call Cv on V if V is not jet created

Comment: becuase what im doing is when I create he new instance of V0003 there is no data loadet on it jet, so then I want to call Cv on that instance which stands for construct View so that it than loads in all the data and when Cv throws its completion handler (So it loadet all the data) than i would like to show It.

Comment: Modify your Cv completion hander      V.Cv { (Con, passed_V) -> Void in

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            self.showViewController(passed_V, sender: self)
        }
    }

Comment: O so you mean that on completion it sends a reverence of itselfe ?

Comment: yes. Completion should sends a reference of itself.